# Leaflet : Invalid LatLng object NaN

Tags: exception, leaflet

My original code was using `L.latLng()` to create a Lat/Long object. It threw an exception.

It was also using variables, but when I hard-coded the values of the variable into my code, I still get the exception.

Why does

```
                const circle = L.circle([103.628251266667, 1.31326251666667], 
                    {
                    color: 'red',
                    fillColor: '#f03',
                    fillOpacity: 0.5,
                    radius: 500
                }).addTo($scope.map);
```

throw

> mapController.js:73 Error: Invalid LatLng object: (103.628251266667, NaN)

Oddly, adding a marker works. Just no a circle, which I would really prefer.

```
            const marker = L.marker(markerLatLng,
                {
                    draggable: false,

                }).addTo($scope.map);
```

does not throw an exception.

I would prefer to use circle, because the radius can be given in metres, and will be affected by scrolling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your coords. Leaflet needs the format `latlng` but you pass `lnglat`.

Why I know that you have to change your coords? Because the max lat value is around `88`

Change your code to:

```
      const circle = L.circle([1.31326251666667,103.628251266667], 
                    {
                    color: 'red',
                    fillColor: '#f03',
                    fillOpacity: 0.5,
                    radius: 500
                }).addTo($scope.map);
```

**Test**

Open [Leaflet Offical Example](https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/example.html)

And add this to the console:

```
const circle = L.circle([1.31326251666667,103.628251266667], 
                    {
                    color: 'red',
                    fillColor: '#f03',
                    fillOpacity: 0.5,
                    radius: 500
                }).addTo(mymap);

mymap.panTo(circle.getLatLng())
```

then you see, that it is working. Really weird that this is not working for you

**Answer**

After a few tests with try and error (look in the comments) we found out that L.circle is not working when the second param are the options. Correct order is `latlng`, `radius`, `options`

So call instead `L.circle([1.31326251666667,103.628251266667],500, {color: 'red'})`

---

[Update] to include a commnent from @Falke

This works:

```
L.circle([1.31326251666667,103.628251266667],
         500,
        {color: 'red',
         fillColor: '#f03', 
         fillOpacity: 0.5}).addTo($scope.map);
```

Comment: You are correct, of course. D'oh! Upvote, but now I get `mapController.js:73 Error: Invalid LatLng object: (1.31326251666667, NaN)`

Comment: I add a "test" to the answer, it is working with the normal javascript leaflet. What framework you are useing?

Comment: I am using AngularJs.  But I have copied the code from one of my other AngularJs projects, where it works just fine. The only difference is the source of the data. But, even hard-coding it, it throws an exception :-(

Comment: Try it with a marker `L.marker([1.31326251666667,103.628251266667])` , ´this is so weird ...

Comment: This is bizarre! It works with marker, but not with circle !

Comment: Had you tried to use the circle without options? `L.circle([1.31326251666667,103.628251266667],500)`

Comment: That works!! Yay!!  If you update your answer, I will accept it. Thanks a 1,000,000. Although I still don't know why I cannot change the colour.

Comment: I updated the answer and i have one more idea, try: `L.circle([1.31326251666667,103.628251266667],500,{color: 'red',fillColor: '#f03', fillOpacity: 0.5})` and please check if you are using the newest leaflet version `1.7.1`

Comment: Yes, that works. Seems that the only difference is to move the radius out of the options. Strange, but I am very, very happy.

Comment: Please add that to your answer, too, and I think that we can finally close this question.